# nodejs is already the newest version but not found

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I am running Kubuntu 20.10. When I run node -v on the terminal I get

```
Command 'node' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install nodejs
```

then I run the command and I get this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version (12.20.0-deb-1nodesource1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I have no idea what is going on. I have tried using node -v and nodejs --version. How can I even begin to troubleshoot something like this?

Comment: I usually install with `wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.15.3/node-v14.15.3-linux-x64.tar.gz` then `sudo tar -xf node-v14.15.3-linux-x64.tar.gz --directory /usr/local --strip-components 1`

Comment: did you install nodejs before?

Comment: No I didn't. I found out about this problem when I decided to work on a project.

Comment: Did you find the issue?